# Iterate through CSV files in a folder and load data into MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I use the following code to iterate through the files in a folder and have the data loaded onto a MYSQL table. I couldn't quite get this working. Is there any better solution?

```
if ($handle = opendir('C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\CSV Files')) {
while(false !== ($entry = readdir($handle)))
{
mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE %handle
                          INTO TABLE main_table
                          FIELDS
                          TERMINATED BY ','
                          OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
                          ESCAPED BY '"'
                          LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
                          IGNORE 1 LINES")
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by you couldn't quite get it to work? Shouldn't the `ESCAPED BY` part be `'\\'`, by the way?

Answer (score 1):

There is so much wrong with your code it's hard to pick where to begin...

- Your directory path is not escaped.
- You do not have anything to tell you that the directory cannot be opened.
- `%handle` is not a PHP variable, and it's the wrong variable besides.
- `$entry` is just the filename, not the full path.
- there's no semicolon at the end of the `mysql_query()` call.
- Your 'enclose' and 'escape' chars are both `"`, neither of which were escaped.
- `echo` the query instead of running it to be sure it's formed correctly if it's not working.
- You never actually check to see if the query was successful.
- turn on error reporting, because you've got some glaring parse errors that should make this script fail before it even runs.
- and the ever-popular: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, you should be using PDO or MySQLi.

So this should probably work a:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
define('DEBUG', true);

$basedir = 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Desktop\\CSV Files\\';
if ($handle = opendir($basedir)) {
  while(false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    $query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE $basedir$entry
                INTO TABLE main_table
                FIELDS
                TERMINATED BY ','
                OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
                ESCAPED BY '\\'
                LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
                IGNORE 1 LINES");
    if(DEBUG) { echo $query . "\n"; }
    if(!mysql_query($query)) {
      die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
    }
  }
} else {
  echo "Could not open $basedir";
}
```

Comment: I added the connection to your code:
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
mysql_select_db("some_db", $con);

and deleted the ')' after "ignore 1 lines"

Comment: I get the following error:
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\CSV Files\. INTO TABLE main_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\' LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' IGNORE 1 LINES Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'C:\Documents and SettingsDesktop\CSV Files\. IN' at line 1

Comment: You have missed quotes around filename, try $query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$basedir$entry' INTO TABLE main_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES");